# I want to transfer money form User A to User B in Paypal, is that possible?

Tags: paypal

Using PayPal API:
Well, I'm starting a startup that helps one user (User A) to send money to other user (User B).
I want User A to pay my company a little for this, but only that.

Is that possible?

It would work like this:

User A wants to send U$ 700.00 to User B. He would have to agree to do it, pay U$ 35.00 as a service fee.
User B gets U$ 700.00.
My company gets U$ 35.00.

Comment: If both users are Paypal users, why would they pay you anything?

Comment: @MikeW I can think of a couple of reasons.

Comment: Paypal already has this business.  Anyone can send anyone else an invoice on paypal, and anyone can send money to anyone on paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Business viability aside, yes it's possible with [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). It's almost exactly the use case you prescribe, although instead of selling a "product" you're selling the transfer itself.

From the docs: "For example, you might use this configuration in a sales commission application that transfers funds owed for commissions from your account to the accounts of your sales force."

Adaptive Payments is what you want.